Alternatives to Wire Flexures for High-Precision Suspension in a Modular Active Air Bearing Platform
I am designing an active air bearing platform where two parallel plates need to be suspended with three planar degrees of freedom relative to each other: x- and y-translation, as well as rotation around the z-axis. Achieving high positioning accuracy is crucial because 19 pins, that are part of the bottom plate, must pass through their corresponding holes on the top plate and remain 200um below the top surface. Additionally, the design is intended to be modular, which requires minimizing the space around the pins.
Current Approach:

Suspension Method: Utilizing three wire flexures.
Adjustment Mechanism: Height adjustments are made using set screws.
Challenges: This method is tedious and difficult for attaining the necessary positioning accuracy.

Design Specifications:

Platform Length: 125 mm
Pin Spacing: 2.5 mm between each pin

Question: Are there any small-footprint alternatives to wire flexures that can provide the desired high positioning accuracy for suspending the parallel plates in this modular active air bearing platform? I'm looking for solutions that simplify the adjustment process while maintaining precise control over the degrees of freedom.


